# jquery datepicker setvalue shows calendar again

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jquery datepicker shows up again when i call setDate function , i have multiple datepickers on my page. when one datepicker value is selected i want to set the values of all other calendars that are showed up and it just hangs until i click the datepicker again, here is how i am doing it. I am using jquery 1.6.1 and jquery-ui-1.8.5

```
function initCalendarMulti() {
    $(".calendarmulti").each(function (index) {
        $(this).datepicker({ 
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: 1,
            maxDate: "+1Y",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            duration: "fast",
            onSelect: setValuesMulti,
            regional: cul
        });
    });
}
    function setValuesMulti(elem, inst) {
    var temp;
    if (segmIndex == 1) return;
    for (var i = 1; i <= segmIndex; i++) {
        var depSrc = $("#segment" + i + " input[id=txtDeparture" + i + "]").datepicker("getDate");
        if ($("#segment" + (i + 1)).hasClass("hide") == false) {
        var id = "segment" + (i + 1) + " input[id=txtDeparture" + (i + 1) + "]";
        var depDes = $("#" + id).datepicker("getDate");
        if (eval(depDes - depSrc) < 0) {
            $("#" + id).datepicker("setDate", depSrc);//this line shows up the calendar again
            //depDes.setDate(depSrc); // this line does not do anything
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: i wonder why i dont have any replies even after 4 days? is stack is really overflow?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be

```
$("#" + id).datepicker('setValue', depSrc);
```